# How to iterate faster through a loop with a range that goes to at least 2 digits (10) until 1000 digits (10^100) using Python 3 +?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, math

I receive a non-empty string S of at most 1000 characters and an integer N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000). Each character of S is either a decimal digit or the character “ ? ”; the leftmost character is not “ 0 ” and at least one character is “ ? ”.

I have to show an integer D without leading zeros indicating the smallest multiple of N that has | S | digits and such that the digits in S are coincident with the corresponding digits in D. If there exists no such an integer D, i write an “ * ”.

So, i managed to write a code that kind do that, but it takes forever for large numbers, i want to find a way to make it faster or if i can improve my code.
Here its an example of input and output:

input: 1??????????????????????????????? 2 / output: 10000000000000000000000000000000

input: ???????????????????????????????1 2 / output: *

input: ?294?? 17 / output: 129404

my code:

```
D, N = input().split()
lenOfD = len(D)

lowerD = ''
higherD = ''
infos = {}

for index, letter in enumerate(D):
    if letter.isdigit():
        lowerD += letter
        higherD += letter
        infos[index] = letter
    else:
        if index == 0:
            lowerD += '1'
            higherD += '9'
        else:
            lowerD += '0'
            higherD += '9'

rest = int(lowerD) % int(N)
quotient = int(int(lowerD) / int(N))

if rest != 0:
    while True:
        result = quotient * int(N)
        resultString = str(result)

        matchInfo = 0
        
        if len(resultString) == lenOfD:
            newRest = result % int(N)
            if newRest == 0:
                for position, value in infos.items():
                    if resultString[position] == value:
                        matchInfo += 1
                    
        quotient += 1
        
        if result > int(higherD):
            print('*')
            break
        if len(infos) == matchInfo:
            print(result)
            break
else:
    print(lowerD)
```

and still have a minor problem, that when a divide a large number for a small one, the precision sucks because it approximate to scientific notation, and that is why i converted the variable quotient to int, but its not converting to the right number.

Comment: When you divide using the `/` operator, you'll always get a float in Python 3. To do integer division (which won't have precision issues when dealing with very large numbers), you can use the `//` operator. Something else that might also improve your performance by a little bit is to use numbers all over instead of strings. You convert `N` to an int a whole bunch of different times, why not just do it once at the start? To get beyond small improvements though, you probably need a more clever algorithm.

Comment: i'll look into your tips, thanks m8. And yeah, probably this code won't give me the speed i need, cause i have to give the answer in 1s.